# Deadlifts and Foam Rolling

Tags: injury-prevention

Thanks for your insight. Can you explain how you perform your deadlifts and also how you perform the foam rolling. What exactly do u do? Thankyou.

Comment: Maybe someone will take the time to answer this, but you should probably buy Starting Strength v3 (book), and watch some youtube videos on foam rolling.

Answer (score 2):

**How to perform deadlifts?**

[Jonnie Candito's How To Deadlift](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u6UgD1H_AXw)

[Jason Blaha's How To Deadlift](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V8bDeB7UPFo)

[Alan Thrall's How To Deadlift](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V8bDeB7UPFo)

So, **how do I know if I'm performing it correctly?**

1.Record yourself deadlifting and watch the replay. Still unsure? Upload your video and post the link here.

2.Get a certified Personal Trainer to check on your form.

**How to foam roll?**

[Alexander Kang's Foam Rolling](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PLmlWuh9Yzg)

[Omarisuf's Foam Rolling](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X6cuNQ23dJI)

If for some reason, your deadlifting looks like this :-

[image: Improper Deadlifting Form]

Consider :-

1.Lowering the weight.

2.Do more stretches/foam rolling.

3.Do more upper back exercises such as [barbell row](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G8l_8chR5BE), [bentover barbell row](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vT2GjY_Umpw), pull ups and etc.